# How to create a floating button in a WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am trying to create a floating button in my WPF application. Currently, I have the following:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Background="#E0E010" Width="50" Height="50" Name="testBtn" Click="testBtn_Click" Margin="374,184,93,35">
        <Rectangle Height="20" Width="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.47,0.456">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Button>
    <ListBox Width="200" Height="200" Name="lbox1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5">
        <Grid Width="175">
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="107,0,0,0"></ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

which has a list box with a scroll viewer and a button outside the list box. When I click the button it prints "Hello World" in the list box. I would like to add the button inside the list box and as I scroll down inside the list box have the button be floating. Is there any way to do this?

Note: I am a complete beginner when it comes to WPF.

EDIT: Here is essentially what I want:
[image]

Comment: do you have an image of what you mean by "floating button"?

Comment: Inside a Grid, items will overlap. Simply move the lines of button after the list, and set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to the desired position.

Comment: Oh, wow that was easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So going off of @omarmallat's comment, the way to do this is

```
 <Button x:Name="addRowButton"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="50"
                    Margin="1275,330,25,25"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Background="#2EFF00" />
```

I had  a margin so the button wasn't directly in the corner and provided a little but of space. Make sure the button tag is inside your grid tag!